# Делфи в сети

Tags: delphi

Помогите описать в Делфи процедуру перезагрузки и выключения компьютера в сети

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое простое

1) на сервере (выключаемый комп) - слушающий сокет, в котором на OnClientRead висит выключение компьютера. Можно проверку на команду сделать вроде

```
if pos('TURN_OFF PASSWORD', UpperCase(Socket.RecieveText)) > 0 then turnOff;
```

в turnOff описан запуск процесса "shutdown -s"

2) на клиенте (выключатель) - активный сокет, соединяющийся с сервером и шлющий команду "TURN_OFF PASSWORD"

Инфа:

- [Пример выключения без shutdown](http://www.delphisources.ru/pages/faq/base/power_off_kill.html)
- [Пример createprocess](http://www.delphisources.ru/pages/faq/base/createprocess_console.html)
- [Пример по ServerSocket и ClientSocket](http://www.delphisources.ru/pages/faq/base/use_ss_cs.html)

**PS** выключение компа, на котором нет сервера выключения есть взлом) Там совсем другая история. И вряд ли здесь место для этого.